# Adding two same css class on menu item

Tags: menus, css

I saw something strange on Wordpress. I explain;

I created a menu, added some pages to it. I added a css class to one of the page item, I saved, no problem. Then I added the same css class name to another page item. I saved, then this page item just disappeared. I tried many times and Wordpress seems to disallow a same css class name to more than one object, like it has to be unique.

Is there a reason why it's like that ?

Comment: do not know what u meant. But everything is ok in my wordpress. I could set up menu item with same css.

Comment: Yeah I don't know. Sometimes it works, and sometimes not. Thanks to have controlled in your side

Comment: Oh I see. Because I made a function to hide menu items with a certain css class but I didn't know that the administration panel uses it too. My bad